# Extract till two values of seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in dataframe named time in format 19:46:23.12
I want to extract it like 19:46:23  and if the value after decimal point is greater than 5 need to round the value before decimal point.
I have tried like:

```
Df['time']=Df['time'].str[:8];
```

Comment: please, read the [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1):

Possible your dataframe has column with type is time. Convert values to datetimes, then round by [`Series.dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) and last convert to times by [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
from datetime import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[time(19, 46, 23, 120000), time(19, 46, 23, 500000)]})

df['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str)).dt.round('S').dt.time
print(df)
              time     time1
0  19:46:23.120000  19:46:23
1  19:46:23.500000  19:46:24
```

If need strings in `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str)).dt.round('S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: if used your `df` the code of the OP should aslo work, so i think there some other trouble.

Comment: @BearBrown - Yes, there are `.astype(str)` - it seems there are times, so converting to strings before.